# Invoking a boost::function through boost::function_base

Tags: c++, boost, boost-function

I have an unordered_map of functions that should be called on an object when an XML file is parsed.
I have found that boost::function has a base class named boost::function_base, however as expected I cannot invoke it because I don't have the signuture of the function.
Since all of those functions are setter functions, I can guarantee that they return void and have only one parameter of an unknown type.
Is there any better way to resolve the type other then an if-else-if branch which I am trying to avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boost::variant is the best way to go. How could you possibly invoke a function with an unknown parameter type, anyway?

Comment: +1 i second that. A variant knows what type is stored, so he can avoid the if-else-if branch.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: But then how can I just call the function? I still need to know the type I am resolving.

Comment: @the_drow look into visitation. boost.variant manual has information on it.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: So I still need to specify the signuture of my functions, right?

Answer (score 0):

`boost::function` is designed for compile time polymorphism only. Why don't you just use a regular function pointer? I.e.

```
typedef void (*function_type)(void *);
```